# Weather Meridians

Tags: fluid-dynamics, meteorology

Are there meridians that effect cloud movement? While observing radar images of moisture bearing cloud movements (at my location in Florida), I've noticed a splitting of the cloud formations a majority of the time. It has become apparent and predictable.

Comment: [Earth Science](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) deals with meteorology.

Comment: The stack exchange Earth Science site that HDE mentions is in beta and we have a general rule to be careful about migrating to beta site. If you would like to have your question migrated there just comment to that effect and a mod will get to it by and by.

Answer (score 0):

No, meridians won't affect cloud movement because there is no meridian which is special due to any geophysical feature.  Latitudes may have an effect due to the 23.5$^o$ tilt of the Earth. The 23.5$^o$N and 23.5$^o$S latitudes mark the maximum latitudes for the Sun to be directly overhead, and the Equator marks the great circle along which there is (nearly) always 12 hours of daylight and 12 hours of dark.

All that said, I would guess that what you see in the clouds is more of a local effect of land and sea causing some type of regular up-draft of warm air which causes the water droplets that make up the cloud to evaporate at the locality. This would have the appearance of the cloud formation ``splitting.''  Or the up-draft could be so strong that it actually pushes the moist, cold air of the cloud apart.

Clouds are dynamic systems, always reforming as moist bundles of air hit cold or warm bundles. The moisture will condense into tiny droplets in the cold air and the droplets will evaporate into water vapor in the warm air.